# Caching Webservices

Tags: java, web-services, caching, weblogic, cluster-computing

I would like to create a wrapper over an existing webservice in order to cache the results.

So i will create a client and I would like to expose this new webservice with a caching mechanism.

Tools I have : Weblogic 10.3 and OSB 10.3 both cluster.

Do you know any free ,simple ,cluster aware cache mechanism that I can use to expose this new cached aware version of the webservice ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On which level would you like to cache? You talk about a client, the client could cache using ehcache or something similar.

Usually, it makes sense to cache on HTTP Server level. You can use a caching reverse proxy (e.g. varnish or squid) and cache your http responses based on specific rules. This makes cache a separate layer from your implementation and scales really well...

Comment: The webservice that i use is developed already by someone else.The new webservice i do is a client of the above webservice and will expose only some reduced functionality.This new webservice will be called very often and we would like to create an application level cache rather then a http one.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any out of the box solutions for caching web services but if you have to implement your own solution then checkout [ehcache](http://ehcache.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Since you're already using Weblogic 10.3, you might be able to use Oracle Coherence without incurring an additional cost. It's a distributed and cluster-aware cache that is integrated to the WebLogic console but it may not be the simplest.